# How to run an android function every 15 minutes , and specifically on the 15 minute mark everyday?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

This maybe a repeated question here but I'm still facing issues on this, hope there's a solution around. Thanks in advance.

How do I set the alarm manager to run so as to execute the function specifically at every 15 minutes clock interval, for example 8:00, 8:15, 8:30, 8:45, 9:00 everyday **regardless of the time when the application is started.**

Take an example if let's say I started my application main activity at 7:47, and I would like the alarm to start at 8:00, followed along with 8:15, 8:30 and etc....how should I do?  I would really appreciate if any suggestions are given..

Comment: i think you need to set up two alarm manager instead of one.

Comment: This is impractical on Android 6.0 and higher. Doze mode will prevent such precise control over timing, unless the user adds your app to the battery optimization whitelist. I strongly encourage you to design your app to avoid needing to do any background work, let alone with this sort of precision.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for the comment, understood that this is impractical for higher versions of Android platform, however I am currently working on a proprietary device running on Android 2.3 where the device will rely on power mode, hence the app will be running on top 24×7 therefore will need to have such tedious work around, do you have any suggestions for such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should setup two alarm manager.for the first one set trigger time by calculating the remain time to your appropriate time (for example 8:00 Am). and after that you should create another alarm manager inside of your first alarm manager that will trigger each 15 minutes.

for calculate time for set first alarm manager use the code bellow:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int m = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int remain=0;
if (m<15)
{
 remain = 15-m;
}
else if (m<30)
{
 remain = 30-m;
}
else if (m<45)
{
 remain = 45-m;
}
else
{
 remain = 60-m;
}
remain=start + remain*60*1000// convert it to milisecond and plus it to current time;
```

**Edit**

and after that you can use code bellow to setup first alarm manager:

```
 AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FirstReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,remain, pi);
```

so now in your FirstReceiver class do something like bellow:

```
public class FirstReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
//do what ever you want + code bellow to setup second alarm manager
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecAlarm.class);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager am=  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                15*60*60,pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this sounds like a possible solution, do you have an example for this ?

Comment: i don't have implemented it but if you want it to be more clear, i can bring some pseudo code.

Comment: @XXX i edit my answer to show how calculate first alarm time.

Comment: @XXX i put some how fully implemented code in my new Edit. i hope it will be useful.

Comment: thanks for the effort on giving me this solution, will try it out

Answer (score 1):

Better to set an alarm clock for every time you want with one day interval

```
public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, yourTimeInMilisecond, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}
```

Here `yourTimeInMillisecond` is the time you want to set alarm, like if you want to set alarm for tomorrow 9 am then it will be :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);       
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
long yourTimeInMilisecond = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however, there's no specific time to set the alarm, I would like to execute the function on start of my activity...so if my activity starts at 7:47, it is still not the 15 minute mark yet, and I only wanted the function to be executed at 8:00 sharp

Comment: @Neo It would be cleaner to use `DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS` instead of calculating time in milliseconds by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
    + (time limits), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Some explanation would be great.

Comment: Without any explanations as to what the code does, or any rationale for proposing this approach, this answer is not helpful. What will happen next is that the person will copy and paste the code and run into problems because you did not provide any explanation. But this was your first answer, so please look at [some tips of making your answer great](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).