# Background service dont work with interval - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, service, background

I have created a background service that start after Boot complete. In background service i start handler with interval from 15 min to check my db and export from db if something new found in db but my handler starts this service after 40; 77; 60; 46; .... minutes!

Here is the code how i start handler

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Start handler
    mHandler = new Handler();
    startRepeatingTask();
    return START_STICKY;
}

void startRepeatingTask() {
    mStatusChecker.run();
}

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            writeLogcat.main("SERVICE Started");

            //Check internet connection
            isInternetWorking();
            //Check for datum
            removeOldFiles();

        }finally {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, 900000);
        }}};
```

And from log cat file i have this interval of handler starting

```
23.01.2017 00:30:01 - SERVICE Started
23.01.2017 01:47:23 - SERVICE Started
23.01.2017 02:39:51 - SERVICE Started
23.01.2017 03:15:08 - SERVICE Started
23.01.2017 03:23:53 - SERVICE Started
23.01.2017 03:33:25 - SERVICE Started
```

How can i do that better?

Comment: Can you show how your Service is defined in manifest?
I'm not sure how this works at all, I think the service could be killed by the OS before the handler posts again. Never tried it that way.

I think you could consider using AlarmManager instead?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788984/how-to-run-an-android-function-every-15-minutes-and-specifically-on-the-15-min

Comment: Here is my service in manifest

`<service
            android:name=".backgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>`

Comment: Using Alarm Manger might give you better results. Want me to write an example?

Comment: When you can write please, thanks